# How to get put $scope.value name inside $('input:radio[name="optradio"][value="$scope.t_color"]') .attr('checked', true);

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am retrieving a row from a database using Angular JS and putting the data inside an editable form; the form consists of multiple radio buttons. I want to make sure when the data is retrieved; the particular radio button gets selected based on the value given in `$scope.radio_val`

```
<td>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="tube" class="form-check-input ml-5"
           name="optradio" value="Grey"> 
    <i class="fas fa-vial" style="color:#757575;font-size: 24px;"></i>
    <span class="ml-4">Grey</span>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="tube" class="form-check-input ml-5"
           name="optradio" value="Black"> 
    <i class="fas fa-vial" style="color:#212121;font-size: 24px;"></i>
    <span class="ml-4">Black</span>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="tube" class="form-check-input ml-5"
           name="optradio" value="Culture"> 
    <i class="fas fa-vial" style="color:#EEFF41;font-size: 24px;"></i>
    <span class="ml-4">Culture</span>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="tube" class="form-check-input ml-5" 
           name="optradio" value="Urine"> 
    <i class="fas fa-prescription-bottle" style="color:#C6FF00;font-size: 24px;"></i> 
    <span class="ml-4">Urine</span>
</td>
```

The above contains a portion of the radio button in the edit form page.

```
$scope.t_color=data.tube;
$('input:radio[name="optradio"][value=" $scope.t_color"]').attr('checked', true);
```

This is what I am trying to do but the AngularJS isn't working

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of JQuery to check the radio button.

Just set the `ng-model` with the value and the radio button with that value will be selected:

```
$scope.tube = data.tube;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. You can do 2 way binding of your radio button as you're already using ng-model.

In your controller code you should do this:

```
$scope.tube = data.tube;
```

And your HTML will stay as-is. You can refer to below official Angular documentation link for more understanding: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D